# maximum value scheduling algorithm

Tags: algorithm, scheduling, time-complexity

I have a list of projects and each project takes you **exactly two days** to be completed and has a due date. let **P[i].id, P[i].duedate, and p[i].value** be the id of the project, the due date of the project, and the value you get if you complete the project on time(on or before due date)

**write** an algorithm that takes as input array A and returns a schedule of which projects you will do and when, to maximize the value you get.
the output of the algorithm is an array B such that B[i] is the id of the  project that you will work on during day i, i>= 1.

no more than one project in a particular date, and you don't get the value of the project unless you complete it by the due date, today is day 0 and you will start working on the projects from day 1 (the due date is an integer), e.g., if the due date of a project is 5, you can choose to work on it on days 3 and 5)

**1- write the algorithm.
2- prove that the algorithm is optimal?
3- what is the time complexity for the algorithm?**

Comment: While this may be an interesting algorithm to look at, what have you done to solve it?  Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Welcome to SO! The SO community does not like "gimme da codez" type "questions". Which is probably why you received a -1 vote. Please try to write the algorithm yourself, if you get stuck, come back and ask a specific question on one thing.

Comment: And your question is? If it's will you do my homework for me the answer is no. However if you google bin packing algorithm, you'll find many more generous than I....

Answer (score 0):

If all the values be same it's simple, just greedy approach by selecting least possible due date works well.

When the values are different, you can use similar approach but this time by dynamic programming (I'll assume your due dates are discrete).

Create an array of size `Max{due date}` name it as `V`, this array holds maximum possible value which can be earned in specific time, and another array for each value in `V` to save the selected tasks in related `V[i]`, now you have this DP choice:

> V[0] = 0, V[1] = max{value_x<sub>1</sub>, V[i] = Max {V[i-2] + value_x<sub>i</sub>, V[i-1]}

Here value_x<sub>i</sub> means maximum value task which has due date equal or smaller than `i`, Also this task shouldn't be in V[i-2] selection, after that update V[i] selection.

Finally I'll left to you to finish your homework by finding the order of this algorithm and it's correctness, also you can improve memory usage.

Comment: @user1380782, I answered for different values, I just remind same value case, to have an intuition for starting with this algorithm, May be I wrote it in bad format and it's not clear for you, now is my sleep time, tomorrow I'll edit it.

Comment: @user1380782, I'd edit my answer.